# jQuery Scale div to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, underscore.js

I am stumped, I have written some code to scale a div within a div. For the purposes of this question I have taken the code out of context to show a working version.

Basically on load and if the user resizes the browser a div its made to dynamically scale so it fits proportionately within the container div.

This all works fine. I have a `dropdown select` to enable the user to change size of the smaller div. It uses `.removeClass` and `.addClass`. Then the scale function is called, however it will only work if the scale function is delayed by a timer i.e;

```
$("#pageSize").removeClass();
$("#pageSize").addClass($("#paper").val());
setTimeout(function(){ 
  scalePages();
}, 1000);
```

This wont work;

```
$("#pageSize").removeClass();
$("#pageSize").addClass($("#paper").val());
scalePages();
```

I am confused why it needs a timer. I have tried to put it in a call back function but still this dosent work. Does anyone have any better solutions to this?

```js
 scalePages();
      
//using underscore to delay resize method till finished resizing window
$(window).resize(_.debounce(function () {
  scalePages();
}, 0));

function scalePages() {                    
  var scaleX = $('.content-article').width() / ($("."+$('#pageSize').attr('class')).width());
  var scaleY = $('.content-article').height() / ($("."+$('#pageSize').attr('class')).height());
  var scale = (scaleX > scaleY) ? scaleY : scaleX; 
  var newLeftPos = Math.abs(Math.floor(((($("."+$('#pageSize').attr('class')).width()) * scale) - $('.content-article').width())/2));
  var newTopPos = Math.abs(Math.floor(((($("."+$('#pageSize').attr('class')).height()) * scale) - $('.content-article').height())/2));
  $('#pageSize').attr('style', '-webkit-transform:scale(' + scale + ');left:' + newLeftPos + 'px;top:' + newTopPos + 'px;');
}
       
$("#paper").change(function() {
  $("#pageSize").removeClass();
  $("#pageSize").addClass($("#paper").val());
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    scalePages();
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
article {
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

#paper {
  float: right;
}

page {
  background: black;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -ms-transform-origin: top left;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  transform-origin: top left;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out !important;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out !important;
  position: absolute;
}
            
.large {width: 5000px;height: 8000px;}
.small {height: 95px;width: 41px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min.js"></script>

<select id="paper">
  <option value="large">large</option>
  <option value="small">small</option> 
</select>                 
                
<article class="content-article">
  <page id="pageSize" class="large">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </page>
</article>
```

Comment: Browsers sometimes delay repainting when you update CSS. You might be able to run getComputedStyle(elem) (on the non-jQuery element) to update it.  Or maybe use requestAnimationFrame(function(){ scalePages() }) instead of a timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question, thanks for the help.  I found out the reason for the timer being needed. It was the CSS transition! (lasting 500ms)

I commented out the lines;

```
-webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out !important;
transition: all 500ms ease-in-out !important;
```

Then took out the timer and worked like a charm! The end result looks better without the transitions anyway as the transition is now immediate.

Full example below...

```js
scalePages();
      
//using underscore to delay resize method till finished resizing window
$(window).resize(_.debounce(function () {
  scalePages();
}, 0));

function scalePages() {                    
  var scaleX = $('.content-article').width() / ($("."+$('#pageSize').attr('class')).width());
  var scaleY = $('.content-article').height() / ($("."+$('#pageSize').attr('class')).height());
  var scale = (scaleX > scaleY) ? scaleY : scaleX; 
  var newLeftPos = Math.abs(Math.floor(((($("."+$('#pageSize').attr('class')).width()) * scale) - $('.content-article').width())/2));
  var newTopPos = Math.abs(Math.floor(((($("."+$('#pageSize').attr('class')).height()) * scale) - $('.content-article').height())/2));
  $('#pageSize').attr('style', '-webkit-transform:scale(' + scale + ');left:' + newLeftPos + 'px;top:' + newTopPos + 'px;');
}
       
$("#paper").change(function() {
  $("#pageSize").removeClass();
  $("#pageSize").addClass($("#paper").val());
  //setTimeout(function(){ 
    scalePages();
  //}, 1000);
});
```

```css
article {
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

#paper {
  float: right;
}

page {
  background: black;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -ms-transform-origin: top left;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  transform-origin: top left;
  /*-webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out !important;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out !important;*/
  position: absolute;
}
            
.large {width: 5000px;height: 8000px;}
.small {height: 95px;width: 41px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min.js"></script>

<select id="paper">
  <option value="large">large</option>
  <option value="small">small</option> 
</select>                 
                
<article class="content-article">
  <page id="pageSize" class="large">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </page>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 scalePages();
      
//using underscore to delay resize method till finished resizing window
$(window).resize(_.debounce(function () {
  scalePages();
}, 0));

function scalePages() {                    
  var scaleX = $('.content-article').width() / ($("."+$('#pageSize').attr('class')).width());
  var scaleY = $('.content-article').height() / ($("."+$('#pageSize').attr('class')).height());
  var scale = (scaleX > scaleY) ? scaleY : scaleX; 
  var newLeftPos = Math.abs(Math.floor(((($("."+$('#pageSize').attr('class')).width()) * scale) - $('.content-article').width())/2));
  var newTopPos = Math.abs(Math.floor(((($("."+$('#pageSize').attr('class')).height()) * scale) - $('.content-article').height())/2));
  $('#pageSize').attr('style', '-webkit-transform:scale(' + scale + ');left:' + newLeftPos + 'px;top:' + newTopPos + 'px;');
}
       
$("#paper").change(function() {
  $("#pageSize").removeClass();
  $("#pageSize").addClass($("#paper").val());
 
});
```

```css
article {
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

#paper {
  float: right;
}

page {
  background: black;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -ms-transform-origin: top left;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  transform-origin: top left;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out !important;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out !important;
  position: absolute;
}
            
.large {width: 5000px;height: 8000px;}
.small {height: 95px;width: 41px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min.js"></script>

<select id="paper">
  <option value="large">large</option>
  <option value="small">small</option> 
</select>                 
                
<article class="content-article">
  <page id="pageSize" class="large">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </page>
</article>
```

Just removed that scalepages function from change function

Comment: Taking out scalepages() causes the function not to run at all!